# How do I send an ajax request and get a response back from a function?

Tags: ajax

I've built a function within a plugin. I'd like to call it with an jQuery ajax function.

The function is defined as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_test_ajax', 'my_test_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_test_ajax', 'my_test_ajax' );

function  my_test_ajax() {    

    $resp = array('title' => 'here is the title', 'content' => ' here is the content') ;        
    wp_send_json($resp) ;

}
```

I then attempt to call the function with from javascript:

```
var target = 'http://'  +  window.location.hostname  + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ;
var data = {
    action: ' my_test_ajax'
} ;
var req = jQuery.post( target , data,  function(resp) { 
    console.log(resp.responseText);
}) ;    
}
```

The site responds from admin-ajax.php. The response carries a '200 OK' header. The body of the response is '0'.

The codex tells me that I can expect this response if the value of 'action' in the post body doesn't match the name of a function hooked to the wordpress ajax hooks. But as far as I can tell, I'm good there.

I'm certain that the function is included in my plugin file.

What are the other barest essentials that I need to get this working?

(I don't want to worry about nonces or localizing js at this point. I just want to get a response from the function before I build up further)

Answer (score 2):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is very simple and you can append more parameters easily in the `data: {action:'my_test_ajax'}` line, try this:

```
var target = 'http://'  +  window.location.hostname  + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$.ajax({
    url: ajax,
    data: {action:'my_test_ajax'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data, data.title, data.content)
    }
});
```

Make sure the `target` points exactly to `admin-ajax.php` or set a global variable (or using localize script) to add a variable where you store the path to `admin-ajax.php` which is `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` in case of confusion.

`$.ajax` does parse JSON data by default, if working with other methods that return the response as is (string) then simply use `JSON.parse(response)` method. JSON that's because you use `wp_send_json($resp)` which returns a JSON object response in the endpoint.

Here's an example of adding more data to the request:

Using `append` method to the data variable or keeping it short and simple as `data: {action:'my_test_ajax', name: 'dave', network: 'wpse'}` and from the `my_test_ajax` function you can get these data by `$_REQUEST[tag]` e.g `$_REQUEST['name']`

**`$.get` ( `$_GET` ) method:**

This one is even more simple and takes less code:

```
$.get( target = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_test_ajax', function( data ) {
    console.log( data )
});
```

Remember to use `$_REQUEST` in your PHP script because it merges all `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` data sets. Unless of course you are sure about the method you're working with.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

1) you have an extra whitespace in code, and that's why it doesnt work:

```
action: ' my_test_ajax'
         ^
```

2) also, you must include  `check_admin_referrer()` !!!!!!!!!

```
function  my_test_ajax() {  
   check_admin_referrer();
    .........
    .........
}
```